# Why do I get an 'Failed to instantiate module app' error in my angularjs test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

In my angular js test I get this error:

```
 Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
        Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
```

Trying to write a unit test for my service, it starts like this:

```
var $httpBackend, httpBasedService;

beforeEach(module('app'));

beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, _httpBasedService_) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    httpBasedService = _httpBasedService_;
}));
```

This is the service:

```
app.factory('httpBasedService', function($http) {
    return {
        getUsers: function() {
            return $http.get('bla')
                .then(function(result) {
                    return result.data;
                });
        }
    };
});
```

karma.conf.js:

```
//jshint strict: false
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

        basePath: './app',

        files: [
            'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
            'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'components/**/*.js',
            'view*/**/*.js',
            'services/myService_test.js'
        ],

        autoWatch: true,

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        browsers: ['Chrome'],

        plugins: [
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-firefox-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-junit-reporter'
        ],

        junitReporter: {
            outputFile: 'test_out/unit.xml',
            suite: 'unit'
        }

    });
};
```

Why do I get this error and how can I fix this?
Here is a link to [github](https://github.com/dimitri-a/angular-seed)

Comment: At a guess, you're not including the file that defines the "app" module in your test config, ie `angular.module('app', [...])`

Comment: can you post your karma.conf.js

Comment: @Sajeetharan it is in the github-repo but pasted it into the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `angular.module('myApp',...` in your app as follow

```
  // Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
  var app=angular.module('myApp', [
```

but using its variable name in test file
try this

```
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
```

instead of `beforeEach(module('app'));`

Hope this help you!